# .htaccess works locally, but gives 404 on GoDaddy

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(design|JS|css|images|remoteLibraries|remoteLibraries/xAJAX/xajax_js/)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?action=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-z_A-Z]+)$ index.php?action=$1&tip=$2
```

It works fine on my local Apache server, but when uploading it to GoDaddy all I get is 404 Not found error ...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1) I recommend that you set a RewriteBase, usually just

```
RewriteBase /
```

which helps standardize where the rewrite takes effect, since the directory structure may be different between the local and remote servers.

2) I also recommend that whenever unexpected rewrite behavior crops up it is important to set

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

so that the Go Daddy 404 page is not redirected as well.